# Angular loop through object from REST API WordPress service

Tags: angular, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Pretty new to Angular and trying to attach a rest API from a WordPress DB into my app. Having issues looping through the object returned to the service call. I can print it out to the view but when I try to loop through it I get this error:

> "ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Example data:

```
{
  "acf": {
    "email_address": "first.last@gmail.com",
    "favicon": false,
    "favicon_png": false,
    "socialmedia_github": "https://www.github.com/"
    "socialmedia_instagram": ""
    "socialmedia_linkedin: "https://www.linkedin.com/"

  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WpOptionsService {
  apiURL = '//myurl.com/wp-json/acf/v3';

  getOptions(): Observable<WpOptions[]> {
    return this.http.get<WpOptions[]>(`${this.apiURL}/options/options`)
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}

export class WpOptions {
  postID: any
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WpOptionsService, WpOptions } from '../../services/wp-options.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-splash',
  templateUrl: './splash.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./splash.component.scss']
})
export class SplashComponent implements OnInit {

  options:WpOptions[] = [];

  constructor(private WpOptionsService: WpOptionsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.WpOptionsService.getOptions().subscribe(optionList => {
      this.options = optionList;
      console.log(typeof this.options);
      console.log(this.options);
    })
  }

}
```

View/HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options">

</div>

<pre> 
  <code>
     {{ options | json }}
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this because its not an array - when one is presenting an object to an ngfor statement it is expecting to loop through an array.

In your particular instance you can strong type to the object using handlebars.

```
 "acf": {
    "email_address": "first.last@gmail.com",
    "favicon": false,
    "favicon_png": false,
    "socialmedia_github": "https://www.github.com/"
    "socialmedia_instagram": ""
    "socialmedia_linkedin: "https://www.linkedin.com/"

  }
```

becomes:

`{{(afc)?.email_address}}` as an example. make sure you use the question mark or you will receive errors because angular is not so patient for the data at first.

If you wanted to take this data and force it to an ngFor loop you can push it to an array - then you could use optionArray on your ngFor

**component typescript**

```
optionArray!: any[]
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.WpOptionsService.getOptions().subscribe(optionList => {
      // this.options = optionList;
    optionList.forEach((option:any)=>{
       this.optionArray.push(option)
    })
      console.log(typeof this.options);
      console.log(this.options);
    })
  }
  }
```

**component html**

```
<ng-container>
<div *ngFor="let option of optionArray; let i = index">
{{option?.afc?.email_address}} {{i}}
</div>
</ng-container>
```

this won't be exact but pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by iterating through the keys to map an array.

Component:

```
export class SplashComponent implements OnInit {

  options:WpOptions[] = [];

  generateArray(obj:any){
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{
      return obj[key]
    });
  }

  constructor(private WpOptionsService: WpOptionsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.WpOptionsService.getOptions().subscribe(optionList => {
      this.options = this.generateArray(optionList);
    })
  }

}
```

And then within the component HTML I can loop through it as I original expected. I can also reach deeper objects

```
<div *ngFor="let option of generateArray(options)">

  {{option.site_email}}

  <div *ngFor="let prof_repeater of generateArray(option.prof_repeater)">

    {{prof_repeater.prof_tax.name}}
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try to prevent using function calls in your templates (bad for performance). In this case, you could also use the keyvalue pipe directly on the object. This saves some code and is better for performance.